# FERPA alternative for German universities

Tags: university, germany, education, privacy

Is there anything similar to US [Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act (FERPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Educational_Rights_and_Privacy_Act) that is valid for German universities, or education system of Germany in general?

I mostly concerned in preserving student's data in electronic form, e.g. am I allowed to share and collect assignments and test results, say, via Dropbox or own server? I hear in US the online data storage must be FERPA-compliant to preserve privacy in the first place, but I don't know what acts and policies govern this case in Germany.

I understand that many universities use own platforms, such as [Moodle](https://moodle.org/), adapted for the current needs, but what should I pay attention to if I want to go beyond?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Note that while I do not consider your question for general laws bad or unanswerable, your university may have its own, much stricter policy on these matters and it’s them whom you probably best ask to solve your problem.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Let's assume that there is no explicit policies at the university level (or nobody really cares), so I'd like to find out what higher-level act or directive I should be aware of in this case. And I'm appreciated for your edit too, I'm still not familiar with the tags on ASE.

Comment: In German a good place to start is the term datenschutz. They tend to take that very seriously. On the other hand I am required to save assignments until the student graduates. So bottom line, you will need to talk to someone locally who can advise you.

Comment: @MaartenBuis "*...someone locally who can advise you*" -- Like an IT-department (IT-Abteilung)? But what if they also cannot help; what normative document on Dataschutz should I read (I'm not a native speaker, but I can read German)? Maybe there is a keyword like "FERPA-compliant storage" that I can use in German (e.g. Dropbox uses it for promotion in education sphere)?

Comment: I would expect more of the legal services. Anyhow I would expect that Dropbox would immediately raise many red flags.

Comment: Also look for a datenschutzbeauftragte

Comment: @MaartenBuis Good point! I guess you can summarize your comments and post an answer then, I would happily accept it; contacting a chief privacy officer is a nice idea indeed.

Comment: @andselisk: "Maybe there is a keyword like 'FERPA-compliant storage' that I can use in German" - That keyword will probably be "Datenschutz-something"; there is no keyword like "FERPA" because privacy laws apply to handling data related to persons in general in Germany. Implications for teaching/student data are typically just derived from the generic privacy rules. (Because of that - and because German laws usually do not come with buzzwordy acronyms ;) )

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Oh, really? :D There are over 20 German acronyms including "Datenschutz" keyword: BDSG, BfD, CEPD, DANA, DSB, DSG, DSG-EKD, DS-GVO, DuD, DVD, EDÖB, EDPS, EDSB, KDO, LDSG, LfD, PDSV, PRev, RDV, SDDSG, TDDSG, ZAfTDa, ZD (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abk%C3%BCrzungen/Gesetze_und_Recht).

Comment: @andselisk: You don't want to claim that abbreviations such as "AAÜGErstV", "AbfVerbrBußV", or "AbsFondsGBeitrV" come anywhere close to "FERPA", "CISPA", or "SOPA" and the like, do you? Even for pronouncable acronyms of German laws such as "ABAG", the German "public" will more likely read them as single letters rather than as a word (i.e. "Ah - Bay - Ah - Gay" instead of "Ahbahg"), in contrast to what is at least my impression from mentions of widely known American (bills of) law(s). In general, I'd say the German law abbreviations are mostly used for shortening text in legal documents, ...

Comment: ... not very much for "public consumption". Point in case, "FERPA" is apparently a well-known and often-used acronym here on [academia.se], and everyone (at least from U.S. academia) immediately knows what is referred to. In contrast, mentioning "BDSG" without establishing the context by mentioning the "Bundesdatenschutzgesetz" or at least "Datenschutz" before will probably earn you the written equivalent of a blank stare among (non-legal professional) Germans. With all that said, note that my comment was meant rather tongue-in-cheek, not as a hard and scientifically proven rule.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper All I'm saying is that German legal system doesn't lack bureaucracy and certainly doesn't lack "buzzwordy" acronyms either. If you can point me towards the right act in this chaos, please feel free to do so, otherwise I'm afraid I don't see your point.

Comment: @andselisk: My point is that there probably is no single keyword to search for beyond "Datenschutz". And that the mere existence of acronyms for any given law does not imply that they are used equally widely as e.g. "FERPA" is.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I see, but that's pretty much what [Maarten Buis's comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/96734/ferpa-alternative-for-german-universities?noredirect=1#comment248913_96734) says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the German Datenschutzgesetz and several state laws, it is forbidden to use private cloud services for storage of personal data. If you are at a university with access to ZENDAS, you can get a review of dropdox [here](https://www.zendas.de/themen/filesharing.html).

A local server is fine, as long as you contact your local "Datenschutzbeauftragten" and announce the service. (S)he might have a form to fill in to evaluate the data security issues resulting from your installation.

Tehre is no specific rule for universities, but the general rules from the German Datenschutzgesetz apply for universities as well.

Platforms like moodle might breake existing German laws, it depends on the configuration of such systems (especially the tracing of activities is a problem).